# Why I don't get user-prompt to turn on GPS?

Tags: android

I have a code using the Location API, and I set the required permission checks (Or so I thought), but when I launch my app, it starts with "Location" permission disabled by default and I have to go to Settings and manually set location permission for my app instead of having prompted upon first launching the app.

The code looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            tv.setText("Not granted");
        } else {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Logic to handle location object
                                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);      
                                tv.setText("Granted");

                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a dialog to turn on GPS or you want a dialog for GPS permission?

Comment: First I want the GPS permission, because my app starts with permission automatically disabled.. and then if possible (If you can show me how) then turning on is also a good option.

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1):

For asking permission I will suggest you use `permission-dispatcher` library.

https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

And to enable GPS:

```
fun locationSetup() {
        LocationServices.getSettingsClient(application)
                .checkLocationSettings(
                        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                                .setAlwaysShow(true)
                                .build())
                .addOnSuccessListener { /*Start location service*/ }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    if (it.error is ResolvableApiException) {
                        try {
                            it.error.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)
                        } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {}
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `requestPermissions()` anywhere. Instead, you are calling `tv.setText("Not granted");`. If you want to request permissions, call `requestPermissions()`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#make-the-request).